# image map brand logo change on hover

Tags: html, css, image, dictionary, hover

I have found a lot of posts that solve this topic however I am still experiencing issues with my code:

```
    <div id="product_tabs_description_tabbed_contents" style="display: block;"><img style="margin-left: -10px; opacity: 1 !important;" src="{{media url="brands.png"}}" alt="" width="754" usemap="#brands_map" /></div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)"><map class="maptest" name="brands_map"> 
<area title="Nike" shape="rect" coords="4,3,73,41" href="#" alt="Nike" class="0" />

<area title="Lonsdale" shape="rect" coords="99,7,168,45" href="#" alt="Lonsdale" class="1" />

<area title="No Fear" shape="rect" coords="206,5,284,42" href="#" alt="No Fear" class="2" />

<area title="Karrimor" shape="rect" coords="317,9,376,62" href="#" alt="Karrimor" class="3" />
 </map> </a>
```

What I have is first.png which is black and white and second.png which is colored. I need to color current brand on hover. Example can be found:http://www.bestsports.sk/

I am using image map but I dont know how to configure css to make it work.  I also cannot aceess my external css file so I have to put the css code directly in html.

Comment: `src="{{media url="brands.png"}}"` Are you sure??

Comment: Also `class="1"` isn't valid and will not work in most browsers, never use a number at the start of a class or id name. See [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the following (I included a nice CSS fade-in transition too)

HTML:

```
<div class="logo">
 <!-- black and white logo --> 
     <img src="batman-logo-bw.png" />
     <div class="logocolor">
        <!-- color logo --> 
        <img src="batman-logo-color.png" />
     </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
div.logo {
  float:left;
  margin:20px;
  position:relative;
}

div.logo div.logocolor {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  opacity:0;
  -moz-opacity:0;
  -webkit-opacity:0;
  -moz-transition:0.2s;
  -webkit-transition:0.2s;
  -o-transition:0.2s;
}

div.logo:hover div.logocolor {
  opacity:1;
  -moz-opacity:1;
  -webkit-opacity:1;
}
```

See my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/XhDBw/1/

You can also remove the second nested div and only go with the img.
In that case apply the following CSS to handle the second image as last-child:

```
div.logo img:last-child {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  opacity:0;
  -moz-opacity:0;
  -webkit-opacity:0;
  -moz-transition:0.2s;
  -webkit-transition:0.2s;
  -o-transition:0.2s;
}

div.logo:hover img:last-child {
  opacity:1;
  -moz-opacity:1;
  -webkit-opacity:1;
}
```

Cheers,

Jeroen

Answer (score -1):

you don't need any map tags to achieve this
you can do this in two ways

```
<li><a href="#" id="first"><img src="blackenwhite.jpg"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="first"><img src="blackenwhite.jpg"></a></li>
```

then change the src attribute of the images via jquery in a hover event

OR

You can do it with just css which is way more easier

```
<li><a href="#" id="first" class="brands">Brand 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="first" class="brands">Brand 2</a></li>
```

This would be the css

```
.brands { text-indent:-1000px;}
#first {background:url('blackenwhite.jpg') no-repeat center center;}
#first:hover {background:url('color.jpg');}
```

do this for each brand 
HOpe this helps :D

Comment: You should never use 2 id's with the same name.